# Why does ppmlhdfe give different results for manually interacted variables?

Tags: regression, stata, interaction, dummy-variable

I am running a regression using `ppmlhdfe` with two dummy variables and the interaction between them. This is constructed as follows:

```
gen interaction = D1*D2 
ppmlhdfe y D1#D2 control i.year, vce(robust)
ppmlhdfe y D1 interaction D2 control i.year, vce(robust)
```

I ran this comparison mostly to see if the results are the same, as the way `esttab` outputs and labels the first version is kind of ugly and confusing. However, while the coefficients on D1 and D2 in the second version match those of D1 = 1, D2 = 0 and D1 = 0, D2 = 1 in the first version, the interaction term is completely different - wrong sign, wrong magnitude, significant in the first version but insignificant in the second. The coefficient on D1 = 0, D2 = 0 which is explicitly outputted in the first version is omitted due to collinearity, so I feel the results really should be identical. I have re-run this using the `reg` command to make sure it's not a ppml issue, but the same thing happened. I have also tried adding the dummies and interaction as explicit factor variables:

```
ppmlhdfe y i.D1 i.interaction i.D2 control i.year, vce(robust)
```

but the outcome did not change.

I have found [this response](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1557238-different-results-from-manual-interaction-term-and-command) to a similar question but using a manual and a continuous interaction term, which is a bit different from my case. I tried to apply it anyway, generating both levels of the first dummy variable and interacting both with the other dummy, as follows:

```
tab D1, gen(d)
gen d1D2 = d1*D2
gen d2D2 = d2*D2
ppmlhdfe y D1 D2 d1D2 d2D2 control i.year, vce(robust)
```

but what happens is that d2D2 is omitted because of collinearity - not surprisingly - and the results are the same. Does anyone have any clues as to why this is?

EDIT1: minimum workable example -

```
sysuse auto.dta, clear
gen high_price = 0
replace high_price = 1 if price>6165
gen interaction = high_price*foreign 
ppmlhdfe trunk high_price interaction foreign headroom, vce(robust)
ppmlhdfe trunk high_price#foreign headroom, vce(robust)
```

EDIT2: please note I have also responded to the Statalist post referenced above, as I realised after posting here that there might be more Stata-specific help available there.

Comment: You don't supply a  MWE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Following advice received on Statalist by Jeff Wooldridge and Carlo Lazzaro I tried

```
ppmlhdfe trunk high_price##foreign headroom, vce(robust)
```

and

```
ppmlhdfe trunk high_price c.high_price#c.foreign foreign headroom, vce(robust)
```

both of which yielded the same result as the manual interaction term. Still not sure what's up with the single # but I conclude it is better to use ##.